# How can I catch a ctrl-c event?

Tags: c++, event-handling, posix, signals, sigint

How do I catch a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event in C++?

Comment: Console application, windows application, or what?

Comment: Which OS Windows, Linux, etc..

Comment: Well, it's a Qt app, but I'm running it from the console during development. (This is Linux)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

`signal` isn't the most reliable way as it differs in implementations. I would recommend using `sigaction`. Tom's code would now look like this :

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_handler(int s){
           printf("Caught signal %d\n",s);
           exit(1); 

}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

   struct sigaction sigIntHandler;

   sigIntHandler.sa_handler = my_handler;
   sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
   sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;

   sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

   pause();

   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: I think my_handler should take `int s` as it's argument.  `sig_t` is itself a function pointer type.

Comment: <stdlib.h>, etc - it's C, not C++. In C++ you should use <cstdlib>

Comment: Works on OSX. In my main.mm file, I didn't even need to include signal.h, stdlib.h, or unistd.h. I just included stdio.h and Foundation/Foundation.h, and then if I needed to do std::cout stuff for outputting a shutdown message, I included iostream.

Comment: `printf()` isn't async-signal-safe, so can't be used inside signal handler.

Comment: These functions are not available on Windows.

Comment: would be nice to have some explanation about `sa_mask` and `sa_flags`.

Comment: @Timmmm No doubt you've figured it out by now, but for anyone else wondering: these are posix calls, which work on Linux and Unix systems. For windows you have to use the windows api.

Comment: @FelisPhasma: Being Posix doesn't really have much to do with it. Windows includes support for a decent number of Posix functions.

Comment: Is there a reason to `exit(1)` instead of `exit(s)` in `my_handler` ? For me this loses information if for instance you want to manage (or just log) exit value (`$?`).

Answer (score 67):

For a Windows console app, you want to use [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) to handle <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd>.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function) for an example.

Answer (score 50):

You have to catch the SIGINT [signal](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Signal/) (we are talking POSIX right?)

See @Gab Royer´s answer for sigaction.

Example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_handler(sig_t s){
           printf("Caught signal %d\n",s);
           exit(1); 

}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
   signal (SIGINT,my_handler);

   while(1);
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's POSIX. I forgot to add Linux to the question.

Comment: signal() behaves differently, depending if it follows BSD or SysV style.  sigaction() is preferable.

Comment: I know it is old, but this does not compile in g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0. I had to change `void my_handler(sig_t s)` to `void my_handler(sig_atomic_t s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is a platform dependent question.

If you are writing a console program on POSIX,
use the signal API (`#include <signal.h>`).

In a WIN32 GUI application you should handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` message.