# how interrupt c++ run without typing neither CTRL-C nor introducing cin or system-pause?

Tags: interrupt

I need to do very long simulation, let's say this:

> int i;
>
> vector result;
>
> while(true)
>
> {
>
> i = random(8);
>
> if (i < 4) {result.push_back(i);}
>
> }
>
> cout << result;

Is there a way to stop this while loop from console doing something (e.g. pressing a key) without typing CTRL-C or without introducing a cin or system-pause function?
I'd like to let this while loop going on until I decide to stop it!

Comment: wouldn't hitting ctrl-c be you deciding to stop it? what's wrong with using ctrl-c?

Comment: hitting ctrl-c the line cout<<result is not executed, while I want it!

Comment: so trap the ctrl-c event and have that handler do your result output.

Comment: ehm... can you write a small example please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-in-a-c-sharp-console-app

Comment: woops. sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c