# Interrupting cin.getline() from another thread on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11

I'm working on my radio transmitter and have just ported it to Linux. Here is the problem:

```
void input_thread()
{
    char buffer[128];
    cout << "Waiting for input\n";
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "say> ";
        if (cin.getline(buffer, 127).fail())
            // Ctrl+C
            break;
        else if (strlen(buffer) == 0)
            continue;
        signal_source.feed(buffer);
    }
}
```

I use a std::thread and hope it break the loop when gets a Ctrl+C. This piece of code works well on Windows but not on Linux. I'm wondering if there is a way to safely break the loop so that I can join the thread without causing deadlock? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl-D` instead?

Comment: Hi. I add a check for eof and it works for Ctrl+D now! But I really want to handle Ctrl+C as well...

Comment: So you need to install a SIGINT handler, yes? Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c).