# Use socket recv function for reading the stream on stdin

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

Can I use socket recv function for reading the input stream of stdin.
i.e for reading the Ctrl-C.

Like.

```
int dummy;

ssize_t bytes = recv (0 /* file descriptor for stdin*/ , &dummy, 1, MSG_PEEK);

if (bytes > 0 && dummy == 0x03)
return true; // Ctrl-C receive
else
return false;        // Not
```

Actually I am reading the stdin stream by using the fgetc function to notify the CTRL-C but sometime fgetc does not notify any CTRL-C.
and if I use recv function as disjunction with fgetc function then every case of notifying the CRTL-C is being handled.

So Can I use socket recv function for reading the stdin stream?
Here is my complete algorithm for notifying the CRTL-C event.

```
ssize_t bytes = recv (data->input, &dummy, 1, MSG_PEEK);

dummy1 = fgetc (stdin)

if ((dummy1 == 0x03) || (bytes > 0 && dummy == 0x03))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use `recv` on non-sockets (at least, not portably or commonly).  FWIW, on some systems, `select` or `poll` can be used to monitor non-sockets including stdin for I/O events, and read/write can be used across sockets and other streams, but recv/send are specifically part of the Berkeley Sockets API standard *for sockets*.

Control-C often generates a signal (specifically SIGINT) for which you can register a signal handler, but details are OS specific.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c).

Comment: But how can I use ungetc function or MSG_PEEK flag like things with read/write function on stdio

Comment: I suggest you use `std::cin`'s [`peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek)  and [`putback`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback), and `std::cout` for output, and not use `read`/`write` for stdin/stdout I/O.