# C++ Call Function When Terminated from Python Subprocess

Tags: python, c++, function, exit, terminate

I'm using C++, Python 3.5, and Windows 7. I'm currently calling a C++ executable from my Python code using subprocess, then terminating the executable using the following code:

```
open = Popen([path\to\exe])
open.terminate()
```

This seems unlikely, but is it possible for my C++ code to call a function in itself when Python calls terminate on it? I've found options for functions to be called when C++ is closed with the X button or by itself, but this question is too specific.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to terminate your C++ code you have to first do things like

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["path\to\exe"])
#... do stuff
#and when you want to terminate it
p.terminate()
```

But you cannot call `Popen` again because it would spawn another instance, that would would kill immediately: useless.

When you terminate the process, it stops it right there like a `kill -9` or a `taskkill /F`. If you want to give a chance to the process to react, do that instead of `p.terminate()`

Windows only:

```
os.system("taskkill /PID "+str(p.pid))
```

Unix & Windows (just read in the docs, but did not test it):

```
os.kill(p.pid,signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
```

(omitting the `/F` flag allows to put a handle in the C++ program to execute some exit/cleanup procedure and then exit)

Edit: to put a handle in the C++ program (`atexit` is just called when you call explicitly `exit`, not working in that case):

- Unix: using signal. That's been explained a million times
- Windows: example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685049(VS.85).aspx. I have tested it and it works when you close the window and with CTRL+C

(source: [How can I catch a ctrl-c event? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c))

Comment: Thanks so much! In that case, would I be able to use std::atexit to call a function at close? If not, how would I get my code to react to being killed?