# Kill C++ application in terminal, destructor not called?

Tags: c++, linux, destructor, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I'm running a C++ application from a Linux terminal. This application allocates shared memory (using Boost Interprocess).

If I kill the application (Ctrl + c) in the terminal I was expecting a destructor to be called. However, it's not, leaving my shared memory still allocated. Therefore when I go to run again, instead of the shared memory being re-created, the existing memory state is opened. This is undesirable.

Is there a way to get the destructor to be called upon cancelling the application in the terminal?

Comment: Capturing a key stroke and then gracefully exiting could be an option.

Comment: You might want to check this SO [How can I catch a ctrl-c event? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c)

Comment: You can *catch* the signal generated by `Ctrl-C` and clean up nicely.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean literally try{....} catch(std::exception& e){}?

Comment: you can set a callback with atexit

Comment: @user997112 no you can't catch signal like that just exeptions

Comment: `SIGKILL` cannot be caught. Also, why do you think memory is still allocated after your app got killed?

Comment: Ok, I read the question once again. `Ctrl+C` raises `SIGINT`, which can be caught on the app side to do some cleanup.

Comment: No, it's not exceptions. Do some searching for *POSIX signals*.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I can tell the shared memory still exists because when I re-run the program, it checks whether it already exists and reports it.