# Tracking clipboard changing data in win32 console application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application, clipboard

I am currently making a win32 console application in c++.

Now, I have to react on the user changing the clipboard content.
Currently I am just checking for the user pressing ctrl+c, but obviously that's not enough since it won't track rightclick->copy, etc.

Sadly i cannot just use the winmessage, since i am developing a console application, hence my application does not have its own hwnd.

And i really do not want to copy the clipboard data 10 times a second or so. 
This is bound to cause problems with other programs since i have to lock and unlock the clipboard every time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641182/107625

Comment: you need register for this clipboard listener (vista+) via [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) and unregister at the end [`RemoveClipboardFormatListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-removeclipboardformatlistener). *hence my application does not have its own hwnd.* - of course this is wrong. nothing prevent you from create window

Comment: you will got [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) when the contents of the clipboard have changed.

Comment: @uwe: That's an unrelated Q&A.

Answer (score 5):

To monitor clipboard changes, you can use the [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) API:

> When a window has been added to the clipboard format listener list, it is posted a [WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) message whenever the contents of the clipboard have changed.

An application that doesn't have a GUI can create a [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) to receive change notifications:

> A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible [...]. The window simply dispatches messages.