# Control+C under Unix

Tags: unix

How does Control+C work in the Unix system?

Usually, Control+C would cause process/application to abort, but some SW applications under the Unix environment have some special feature with it. Like it would trigger some special running mode, or save an intermediate copy of the run.
Could someone explain how this feature is achieved?

Comment: There is a useful answer according to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641223/9967624

Comment: Do some research about [*signals*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html). There are plenty of tutorials about them all over the Internet, and all decent UNIX and POSIX related books should cover them.